# Two-way IPC communication using ADB

Tags: adb

I need to be able to communicate with a component on an Android 8 device on a specific port on the device. One way communication is fine because I either reverse-forward a connection and listen on the host or forward a connection and input on the host.

Is there a simple solution to two-way communication? I would like to avoid having to swap the direction of the connection on each exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I misunderstood the way `adb forward` and `adb reverse` work. The are not one way channels, but two way. The difference is that `adb forward` connects to a port on the device and binds to a port on the host, and `adb reverse` does the opposite.